# Reference non-GAC version of DLL in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reference, gac

This is similar to [Add Non-GAC reference to project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/387093/add-non-gac-reference-to-project) but the solutions presented there don't seem to help.

I have a WinForms UI Library (Krypton from ComponentFactory) installed in the GAC.  There's a bug I want to track down in that library, so I added the source code to my solution, removed the old references from my WinForms project to Krypton DLLs, added them back as a project references, ensured Copy Local is set to true, double-checked that the path (on reference properties tab) points to my local project, and...

...the GAC version is still being used while debugging.  I cannot set a breakpoint in the Krypton source, `Debugger.Break()` or other code changes to not execute, and when I start the Visual Studio 2010 debugger, I see a Loading from ... GAC_MISL message relating to the Krypton DLLs flash by in the VS 2010 status bar.  The DLLs are not copied to the WinForm's Debug folder.

How can I reference the "project" version of the files while debugging while leaving them registered in the GAC?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The CLR will *always* look in the GAC first.  Don't hesitate to use gacutil.exe /u to remove them.  Hacking the [AssemblyVersion] would work too so that the GAC copy won't be a match.

Comment: gacutil seems to be located in several places - try searching in `C:\Program Files (x86)\ `. This is one of the paths on my server: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\x64`

Comment: Is this still true? Is there now way to prioritise the referenced project instead of the GAC? It seems to me a major flaw in a debug context; Microsoft should address this IMHO.

Comment: It was true, it is still true, it will always be true.  You'll have to talk to Microsoft but you can be pretty sure up front that they are going to completely ignore you :)  Abusing the GAC on your dev machine is just a plain bad idea, it is a deployment detail that only matters on the user's machine.  That's the real victim of DLL Hell.  Having hell on a dev machine is a self-inflicted problem.